# Docker nginx responds 403 if you are offline

Tags: docker, nginx

Im running docker with nginx, PHP and MariaDb in my company.
But if my laptop is offline or Im connected with vpn the nginx responds with an 403 error. Docker is starting normally. Do you have any idea why I get the 403 from nginx?

Maybe Its because of the mounted drives?

```
2018/06/05 13:23:20 [error] 5#5: *3 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is 
forbidden, client: 172.21.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: 
"localhost"
172.21.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2018:13:23:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 572 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Edit: I figured out that I cant mount the shared drives. I got an error that the firewall blocks it.

Comment: Maybe you can teach me which informations are necessary?

Comment: Maybe you can show us anything related to your case? Logs at least. Nginx can be put in a debug mode you know. We don't read tea leaves here Ted.

Comment: I added the latest error log :)